# How do I edit a specific value in my state?

Tags: reactjs

I was recently able to delete my item following this pattern:

I passed in a function with `onClick={() => props.onDelete(todo)}` in:

import React from 'react';

```
const Todo = props => (
    <div>
       <ul className = "list-group">
       {props.todos.map(todo => {
          return <li className = "list-group-item" key ={todo.id}>{todo.text}<a onClick={() => props.onEdit(todo)}
          className="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" href="#"></a><a onClick={() => props.onDelete(todo)}
          className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" href="#"></a></li>
        })
      }
    </ul>
      </div>
);

export default Todo;
```

And then had the handler do the following:

```
  handleDelete(todos) {
var prevState = this.state.todos;
for(var i = 0; i< prevState.length; i++){
  if(prevState[i].id == todos.id){
    prevState.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
this.setState({prevState:todos})
```

}

That was good and is done. However, now I would like to **edit**  the todo's `todo.text` and `setState` with the newly edited text for that **specific** todo item, the same as I was able to delete that specific todo item.

I have created a function that I passsed in `onClick={() => props.onDelete(todo)}` as well as a handler but within it I effectively want code that  produces the ability to edit the specific todo

```
handleEdit(todos) {

  }
```

How do I edit my specific todo? I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Create a copy of the `todos` and completely replace it with a new array `this.setState({prevState:newTodos})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need UI to handle the edited text. For example, you can render a `textarea` with the todo text when the user clicks "Edit".

After the user edits the text and clicks the "Save" button then update the `state`.

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/64qkjlk2oz

```
class TodoList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            todos: [
                { id: 1, text: 'Buy milk' },
                { id: 2, text: 'Wash car' },
                { id: 3, text: 'Feed dog' }
            ],
            editId: 0,
            editText: ''
        };
    }
    showEdit = (event, todo) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            editId: todo.id,
            editText: todo.text
        });
    }
    handleSave = () => {
        const { editId, editText } = this.state;
        const todos = [...this.state.todos];
        for (let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
            if (editId === todos[i].id) {
                todos[i].text = editText;
                break;
            }
        }
        this.setState({todos, editId: 0, editText: ''});
    }
    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({editText: event.target.value});
    }
    render() {
        const { todos, editId, editText } = this.state;
        return (
            <ol>
                {todos.map(todo => {
                    return editId === todo.id
                        ? <li>
                            <textarea onChange={this.handleChange}>{editText}</textarea>
                            <button onClick={this.handleSave}>Save</button>
                        </li>
                        : <li>
                            <span>{todo.text + ' '}</span>
                            <a onClick={e => this.showEdit(e, todo)} href="">Edit</a>
                        </li>
                })}
            </ol>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit todos and refactoring of existing remove handler will looks like this:

```js
handleDelete(id) {
  const todos = this.state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id === id);

  this.setState({
    todos
  })
}

// pass updated todo item. 
// if you want just edit 'text', just pass here and object {text: 'new_next'}
handleEdit(editedTodo) {
  const todos = this.state.todos.map(todo => {
    return todo.id === editedTodo.id 
      ? {...editedTodo}
      : _todo
  });

  this.setState({
    todos
  })
}

const Todo = props => (
<div>
   <ul className = "list-group">
   {props.todos.map(todo => {
      return 
      <li>
        <a 
          onClick={() => props.onDelete(todo.id)} // pass actual todo id into handler
          className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"
        />
        <a 
          onClick={() => props.onEdit(editedTodo)} // pass here edited todo
          className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"
        />
      </li>
    })
  }
</ul>
  </div>
);
```